# Spring security and remoting

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-remoting

i am using spring remoting alongside spring security
I have 2 servers (let's call them "front" and "back")
The "front" server is exposed to the outside world and receives, along with the rest of the request, the "Authorization" header. However, i notice that when i use spring remoting to call the "back" that header is not copied. What do i do?
BTW, I haven't checked it yet but i am almost certain that it won't work for "JSESSIONID" as well.. what do i need to do in order to propagate these 2 headers?

Comment: What are the servers? Are you running the common Apache + Tomcat as "front" and "back" or something else?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spring-Remoting, then `spring-security-remoting` to the rescue! This module contains several request factories and executors that enrich the requests with a security context.

For RMI: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/remoting/rmi/package-summary.html

For HTTP: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/remoting/httpinvoker/package-summary.html

Comment: I've looked it up. however it looks like this class has been removed in spring security 3. is there any alternative?

Comment: It's still there but in a separate JAR: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-remoting/3.1.0.RELEASE/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But this solution does not allow for connection pooling, which i need. Is there an example that inherits from the CommonsHttp...Executor?

Comment: You could simply look at the code of `AuthenticationSimpleHttpInvokerRequestExecutor` and copy the behavior to `CommonsHttp...Executor` to configure the request with the current security context. See http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/examples/BasicAuthenticationExample.java?view=markup for an example.